# algebraic and topological dual (vector space)

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

If we have a infinite dimensional topological vectorspace $X$, how can one show that the algebraic dual $X^*$ and the topological dual $X'$ are not the same. We thought about using the fact that for $X$ every neighbourhood filter of zero has a countable basis.

Comment: This is not true in general. Take any linear space $X$ and put the weak topology on it w.r.t. $X^*$. Then $X'=X^*$. This is true, however for infinite dimensional **metrizable** topological spaces. You have to put some additional assumption on $X$.

Comment: Actually I want to show that $X^* \neq X'$.

Comment: Yes, and I gave you an example (actually infinitely many examples) of infinite dimensional topological space $X$ with $X^*=X'$. So you can't show that without some additional assumption on $X$.

Comment: Yes I see, you are right.
I had a formulation misstake in my question:
Lets assume we have a infinite dimensional topological vectorspace  $X$ where every neughbourhood filter of zero has a countable basis and we want to show that $X^* \neq X'$.

I understand your example from above, but I have trouble to formulate a proof for the case mentioned in this comment.